# $K_n=R,C$ or $H$ is the maximal commuting subalgebra for an irreducible real representation of $Cl_n$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, geometry, representation-theory, spin-geometry

Let $Cl_n$ denotes the clifford algebra generated by quadratic form of signature $(n,0)$. Since $Cl_n$ is either of the form $K(2^m)\oplus K(2^m)$ or $K(2^m)$ where $K=R,C,H$, real, complex and quaternion respectively and $K(2^m)$ is ring of $2^m\times 2^m$ matrices with entries in $K$.

"Let $K_n=R,C$ or $H$ denote the maximal commuting subalgebra for an irreducible real representation of $Cl_n$"

$\textbf{Q:}$ What is the meaning of the sentence here? Is $K_n$ identified in the image of representation or just in $Cl_n$? Let $W$ be a left $Cl_n$ module. Then $Cl_n\to End_R(W)$ defines representation of $Cl_n$ where $End_R(W)$ is $R-$linear endomorphism ring. Since $Cl_n$ is either $K(2^m)$ or $K(2^m)\oplus K(2^m)$ with $K=R,C,H$, it is clear that $R,C$ could be maximal commuting subalgebra for $Cl_n$. I do not see why $H$ could be maximal commuting subalgebra as $H$ is non-commutative.

Ref. Spin Geometry, Lawson Chpt 1, Sec 5.

Comment: Perhaps $H$ actually means the [hyperbolic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split-complex_number)? They're commutative, and may be written as $\mathbb R\oplus\mathbb R$ (using the diagonal basis).

Comment: @mr_e_man $H$ means quaternion to me as $Cl_{2,0}$ is isomorphic to quaternion.

Comment: The real numbers are $Cl_{0,0}$, the complex numbers are $Cl_{1,0}$, and the hyperbolic numbers are $Cl_{0,1}$. Are you sure the author meant quaternions? If so, I can only join in your confusion at "commuting subalgebra".

Comment: @mr_e_man, $Cl_{r,s}$ means $V$ equipped with quadratic form of signature $(r+,s-)$. Now $Cl_{1,0}$ is complex number and $Cl_{0,1}=R\oplus R$ where I always consider the base ring is real number $R$. Due to $Cl_{r,0}\oplus_R Cl_{0,2}\cong Cl_{0,r+2}$(there is a $(r,0),(0,2)$ reversed isomorphism as well), this means $Cl_{0,r+2}$ becomes quaternion algebra.

Comment: Do you have a quote from the book saying that $H$ is intended to mean $Cl_{2,0}$ (quaternions) and not $Cl_{0,1}$ (hyperbolic numbers)?

Comment: @mr_e_man pg 25, beginning of sec 4, "we shall give an explicit description of the algebras $Cl_{r,s}$ as matrix algebras over $R,C$ or $H$(=quaternions)..."